# how to add custom swing components to data controls palette in Jdeveloper 12c?

Tags: java, swing, jdeveloper, palette, data-controls

Can someone please help me to add JDateChooser in swing components data controls palaette in jdeveloper 12c? I tried to search in Oracle documents but got no help from them.